# checking the existence of input with a given class in the table by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

**Desc:**

I have a table, x:rows, y:colums

in mostly rows are the same structure inputs (class/type etc.), but not in everyone.

I calculate by javascipt entire tables by class.

in those which I do not have when entering fields with values ​​(those given by the user)

if there is no field in the line and the field is declared in javascript (by class), [that the result should be entered there]

**for exp.:**

> VM36:473 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
>       at updateRowX (:473:35)
>       at HTMLTableElement. (:491:9)

because in this row I dont have input with class for exp. "additional_free" (such as the example below)

```
 function updateRowX(row) {
        let inputs = {}
        for (let input of row.querySelectorAll("input")) inputs[input.className] = new TimeInput(input);
        let { start, end, normative, actual, overtime, additional_work, additional_free, nulladditionalnull_work_null, additional_night } = inputs;
        if (!start) return; // Not a data row

        let diff = actual - normative;


        if (overtime == 0) {
            additional_free.value = Math.min(0, 1);   <---- here
            nulladditionalnull_work_null.value = Math.min(0, 1);
        }
        if (overtime < eightHours && overtime != 0) {
            additional_free.value = Math.max(0, overtime); <---- here
            nulladditionalnull_work_null.value = Math.min(0, 1);
        }

        if (overtime > eightHours) {
            additional_free.value = eightHours; <---- here
            nulladditionalnull_work_null.value = Math.max(0, overtime - eightHours);
        }
    }
```

**My question:**

is it possible for the program to check in these places if this variable exists?

Did I describe the problem well?

Comment: Share the html as well. Perhaps a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** if there is no input with class `overtime`, `overtime` will not equal to `0`, but will be `undefined`

**2.** in your code, if there is more then one input with same class, the last one will override the previous

**3.** In the case `overtime` is defined, it will be of type `TimeInput`. not a number. so how you compare it as a number?

anyway, if you want to set value of `additional_free` only if it is not `undefined`, you can do:

```
additional_free && (additional_free.value = Math.min(0, 1));
```